# Why isn't this simple jQuery code working?

Tags: jquery

I am only 2 days into jquery so I'm probably making a simple error here. Basically I have a input field that when clicked gets a blue border around it (doing this by having a css class be added to the input field on keyup and the css adds the border color). On keyup the submit button also shows. The only other thing I want is to show a remaining character count. Everything else works except the last part. Here's all my code:

```
<style type="text/css">.onFocus { border:3px solid #BBDAFD; }</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.submitButton').hide();
        $('.remaining').hide();

        var typed = $('input1').val();

        $('.input1').keyup(function(){
            $('.input1').addClass('onFocus');
            $('.submitButton').show();
            $('.remaining').show().html(150 - typed);
        });

    });
</script>

<form action="submitComment.php" name="" method="post">
    <label>Leave a comment</label>
    <input type="text" class="input1" maxlength="150" />
    <br />
    <span class="remaining"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="button" name="commentSubmit" value="Submit Comment" class="submitButton" />
</form>
```

Instead of executing the operation 150 (which is the max character limit I want to allow) from the present value of the input field which should be stored in the variable "typed", instead jquery just splits out:

> NaN

What is the problem/solution here?

### EDIT

Opps, just noticed that this:

```
var typed = $('input1').val();
```

should be:

```
var typed = $('.input1').val();
```

Now NAN doesn't show but 150 shows. So the operation is still not being performed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
    var typed = $('input1').val();

    $('.input1').keyup(function(){
        $('.input1').addClass('onFocus');
        $('.submitButton').show();
        $('.remaining').show().html(150 - typed);
    });
```

Needs to look like this:

```
    $('.input1').keyup(function(){
        $(this).addClass('onFocus');
        $('.submitButton').show();
        $('.remaining').show().html(150 - this.value.length);
    });
```

It's important to check the current value length **inside** the `keyup` handler, otherwise you're always checking against what the value length was on `document.ready`.

Answer (score 0):

Put this as first line in keyup event handler

```
var typed = $('.input1').val().length;
```

and remove `var typed...` from above.

Changes

1. You want `typed` to be computed each time input value changes, not once when page is loaded.
2. You missed a dot in selector (`'input1'`)
3. Use `length` function to get input size

**edit**
Nick Craver has posted a better way to do this, I leave it here just to point out mistakes.

Comment: Just did all that you said, but the number is stuck at 149 even though it's within the keyup handler it's not changing with every key press for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
var typed = $('input1').val();
```

Should probably be:

```
var typed = $('.input1').val();
```

Second:

If you're trying to get how many characters are typed in, you should probably use:

```
var typed = $('.input1').val().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're effectively trying to subtract "150 - whatever I typed". So it's spitting out `NaN`, or `Not a Number`. You want the length, no the actual value.

```
var typed = $('.input1').val().length; // This will have the actual text

$('.remaining').show().html(150 - typed.length); // (150 - 24) as an example
```